# Vba PublishObjects- How resize to in html?

Tags: html, excel, vba

The following code publish a range from Excel to an HTML file. Is there a way to make the published range to be of different size than the default one? Alternatively how could I publish an Image version to the range to the same file?

```
ObjectToPaste = xlApp.Range(UserformObj.listCharts.SelectedItem).Address
            Title = UserformObj.listCharts.SelectedItem.SubItems(4)
            Caption = IIf(KUKUKU3 = 1, Title, "")
            On Error Resume Next
            With oWB.PublishObjects.Add(xlSourceRange, Where, sht, _
                                        ObjectToPaste, xlHtmlStatic, "", Caption)
                .Publish (False)
                .AutoRepublish = UpdateHTml
            End With
            On Error GoTo 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194386.aspx), you can set the Source Range. (See "$G$3:$H$6")

Example:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _ 
 Filename:="\\Server\stockreport.htm", Sheet:="First Quarter", Source:="$G$3:$H$6", _ 
 HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic, DivID:="Book1_4170") 
 .Publish (True) 
 .AutoRepublish = False 
End With
```